XSS through preg_replace("/<[^>]+?>/", "", $string);
I am working on a lab for my computer security class and I am stuck on the extra credit of the lab. The goal is to find a vulnerability in the sanitization function. I found my way through the required problem rather quickly but I have been stuck on this one for a solid 4-5 hours. The given sanitization functions runs in a do while loop until it detects the string has no more open < with a close >. Here is the code:
preg_replace("/<[^>]+?>/", "", $string);
My understanding of the code from testing is that it removed anything between an open < until it finds a >. It will do this for the entire string (it will also remove the < and >.
Please keep in mind I am new to XSS but I tried:
I have tried using &lt and &gt
I have tried using stacked < and >
I have tried using / , " \ etc... in order to try and escape the detection
I have tried many of the solutions found on
https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet.html
